# How can a files without extensions be renamed through Nuspec

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

The [.nuspec File Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuspec) says that files without extensions can be selected in the following manner:

> To include files without an extension, use the * or ** wildcards:
>
> ```
> <file src="flags\**" target="flags" />
> ```

And, then also says that files can be rename in this manner:

> ```
> <file src="ie\css\style.css" target="Content\css\ie.css" />
> ```

How can both this functions be combined to rename `LICENSE` to `AssemblyName.license.txt`? I have tried the following without any success:

```
<files>
    <file src="../LICENSE*" target="./NHibernate.license.txt" />
    -AND-
    <file src="../LICENSE**" target="./NHibernate.license.txt" />
</files>
```

Comment: For the time being, I have bodged this by making a copy of `LICENSE >> LICENSE.txt` before `nuget pack`. Then, deleting the file after the package has been created.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rename files using wildcard. To do what you would like to do, you will need to list out each file individually in the .nuspec file.

```
<file src="../LICENSE1" target="./1.license.txt" />
<file src="../LICENSE2" target="./2.license.txt" />
```

If you are frequently adding license files, you may wish to continue making a copy of all files before packing.